# selenium 3.0 webdriver for safari 10 on yosemite

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

I have a mac yosemite with Safari 10 that I'm trying to upgrade to running selenium webdriver 3.0. and I cannot get the remote webdriver to start it. It is throwing the following errors:
1. Exception: SafariDriver requires Safari 10 running on OSX El Capitan or greater
when in java I include:

```
capability.setCapability(SafariOptions.CAPABILITY, new SafariOptions());
capability = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
capability.setPlatform(platform);
```

my node is setup using:

```
{
    "browserName": "safari",
    "version":10,
    "maxInstances": 5,
    "platform": "YOSEMITE",
    "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
}],
"proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
"maxSession": 5,
"port": 5000,
"register": true,
"registerCycle": 5000,
"nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
"nodePolling": 5000,
"unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
"downPollingLimit": 2,
"debug": false
```

and: started with:

```
java -Xmx512m -jar \
 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver \
 -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver \
 $JFILE \
-role node \
-hub http://$hub/grid/register \
-nodeConfig $CONFIGFILE
```

I have the safari extension included in my Safari 10 browser.
Do I need to downgrade it? It worked fine under Selenium 2.53.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Yosemite safari 10 not included safaridriver, you should downgrade your selenium version 2.48.0 [look here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/). Or update your OS to macOS Sierra. Read about it [here](https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/)